# how to understand golang "non-Separator characters" at path.Match

Tags: go, embed

When I use golang's embed package, I encounter confusion about path matching. that's what `*` refers to?

Officially called `non-Separator characters`

Here: https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match

```
'*' matches any sequence of non-Separator characters
```

At first I understood `non-Separator characters` meant forward slashes(leading slash `/`), but the following example shows that this is not the case.

```
# dir tree
├── stubs
│   ├── hello.txt
│   └── xyz
│       └── zyx.txt
└── hello.go
```

```
# source file for hello.go
package main

import "embed"

//go:embed stubs/*
var T1 embed.FS


//go:embed stubs*
var T2 embed.FS


func main() {
   s, e := T1.ReadFile("stubs/hello.txt")
   fmt.Println(string(s))
   fmt.Println(e)
   s, e = T2.ReadFile("stubs/xyz/zyx.txt")
   fmt.Println(string(s))
   fmt.Println(e)
}
```

Then run `go run hello.go` will execute successfully.

This case tell me `*` can match `/`.

**what does `non-Separator characters` mean?**

Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`T2.ReadFile("stubs/xyz/zyx.txt")` works for a different reason than you think.

The documentation for `go:embed` explains:

> If a pattern names a directory, all files in the subtree rooted at
> that directory are embedded (recursively), except that files with
> names beginning with ‘.’ or ‘_’ are excluded.

*https://pkg.go.dev/embed#hdr-Directives*

You have declared `T2` as:

```
//go:embed stubs*
var T2 embed.FS
```

The pattern `stubs*` matches the directory `stubs`, so the whole directory `stubs`, including all files in it (recursively) are included in the `T2` filesystem.